# Can I carry a poker chip set to the USA on a student (F1) visa?

Tags: usa, local-customs

Can I carry a poker chip set to the USA on a student (F1) visa?

I am going there for a masters degree for two years, if that matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't imagine any reason why you could not.

Playing poker for money in the US may or may not be legal, depending on the state and the details of your game (I am not a lawyer so cannot advise you on specifics). But the chips themselves are perfectly legal. You can buy them at any game store, or the game section of a large store like Target.

High quality poker chips are heavy, and airlines limit the weight of your luggage, so make sure you are under their limits to avoid steep extra fees. You may want to consider just buying a new set in the US.

Comment: The chips are also not uncommon for students to have (since this is tagged local-customs). Also, not only are poker chips legal, but playing poker for just chips is perfectly legal.

Comment: Can confirm, plenty of students have poker chips in college.